# Localização de dispositivos via bluetooth, android 6.0

Tags: android

Estou tendo dificuldade com o bluetooth, exatamente com a localização de outros aparelhos, tendo em vista que isso só acontece com android superior a 6.0, pois testei em um aparelho com android menor que 6.0 e funcionou.
 Quero saber como faço para funcionar, se há alguma permissão ou algo do tipo que eu possa incluir no código.

Desculpem a falta de conceito técnico, sou novato no ramo de programação, se puderem me dar um help agradeço desde já.

DEVICELIST

```
static private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> btDevices = null;

private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID
        .fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
// UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

static private BluetoothSocket mbtSocket = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle("Dispositivos Bluetooth");

    try {
        if (initDevicesList() != 0) {
            this.finish();
            return;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        this.finish();
        return;
    }

    IntentFilter btIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mBTReceiver, btIntentFilter);
}

public static BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
    return mbtSocket;
}

private void flushData() {
    try {
        if (mbtSocket != null) {
            mbtSocket.close();
            mbtSocket = null;
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        if (btDevices != null) {
            btDevices.clear();
            btDevices = null;
        }

        if (mArrayAdapter != null) {
            mArrayAdapter.clear();
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            mArrayAdapter = null;
        }

        finalize();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }

}
private int initDevicesList() {
    flushData();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Bluetooth não suportado!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return -1;
    }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_devicelist);

    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return -2;
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Obtendo todos os dispositivos Bluetooth disponíveis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    return 0;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> btDeviceList = mBluetoothAdapter
                        .getBondedDevices();
                try {
                    if (btDeviceList.size() > 0) {

                        for (BluetoothDevice device : btDeviceList) {
                            if (btDeviceList.contains(device) == false) {

                                btDevices.add(device);

                                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                                        + device.getAddress());
                                mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }

            break;
    }
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mBTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            try {
                if (btDevices == null) {
                    btDevices = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_devicelist);
                }

                if (btDevices.getPosition(device) < 0) {
                    btDevices.add(device);
                    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                            + device.getAddress() + "\n" );
                    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.fillInStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position,
                               long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Conectando à " + btDevices.getItem(position).getName() + ","
            + btDevices.getItem(position).getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Thread connectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                boolean gotuuid = btDevices.getItem(position)
                        .fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                UUID uuid = btDevices.getItem(position).getUuids()[0]
                        .getUuid();
                mbtSocket = btDevices.getItem(position)
                        .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                mbtSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                runOnUiThread(socketErrorRunnable);
                try {
                    mbtSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mbtSocket = null;
                return;
            } finally {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        finish();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    connectThread.start();
}

private Runnable socketErrorRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Não é possível estabelecer conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Atualizar a digitalização");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case Menu.FIRST:
            initDevicesList();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mBTReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

MAIN

Comment: Coloque pelo menos um trecho do código, se for possível.

Comment: Porque diz que não funciona? Dá algum erro?

Comment: No caso ele não dá erro, porem não aparece nenhum aparelho bluetooth próximo, a list fica vazio, porém em um aparelho com android abaixo de 6.0, aparece todos os aparelhos.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser que o aplicativo inicie a descoberta de dispositivos ou manipule configurações do Bluetooth, será necessário declarar também a permissão BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, além da permissão BLUETOOTH. A maioria dos aplicativos precisa dessa permissão somente para poder descobrir dispositivos Bluetooth locais. Os outros recursos concedidos por essa permissão não devem ser usados, a menos que o aplicativo seja um “gerenciador de energia” que modifique configurações do Bluetooth mediante solicitações do usuário.